# php form validation n show message on form for 3 seconds and fades out

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in php , can any one help me to validate php form using javascript and also show the result on form (in div with java-script) which shows validation message for 3 seconds and then fades out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For form validation refer this link
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html

For displaying messages for 3 seconds refer this
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadeout